# Costmap subscribe problem in hydro

Tags: ros, navigation, occupancy-grid, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I'm now working on navigation stack in hydro. I want to use a global costmap to implement a new algorithm for path planning. So I created a node and subscribe to /move_base/global_costmap/costmap which is nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid type. The problem is this node receive costmap only one time when it come up and never update. In rviz everything is fine. Any idea ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139046/costmap-subscribe-problem-in-hydro/) by [noizpgt](https://answers.ros.org/users/13196/noizpgt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You also need /move_base/global_costmap/costmap_updates

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0